# mySQL Query Remove Null Records in Column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a large mySQL database and I want to remove every record that is empty, not null in a certain column. What is the best way to do write a SQL query for this?

Currently I have tried:

```
 DELETE FROM Businesses WHERE WEBADDRESS IS NULL
```

But it did not delete anything. There are 44,000 records and almost 80% of them are null in that column.

Comment: Fixed your question based on your comment. This is a much better SO question now, providing some information on what you have done and more context for people trying to help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE myColumn IS NULL
```

Link to MySQL page for DELETE syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html

IF the column is not `NULL` but just blank you would need to do something like:

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE myColumn = ''
```

Based on the information you also provided in the comments, the values are likely being loaded as empty (`''`) and not `NULL`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-null.html

The second query should work.

Comment: I tried it, but it did not delete anything. There are 44,000 records and almost 80% of them are null in that column.

Here is my query 
    DELETE FROM Businesses WHERE WEBADDRESS IS NULL

Comment: Do you have a foreign key dependency on these records? Is there any error message? Is the column actually null or just blank?

Comment: I had a CSV file that has 19 columns, so I created a table and named each column like the CSV had them and made them all VARCHAR 255, then imported the CSV. The import was successful with no errors and I made no other changes to the table structure.

Comment: oh I see, null is different than being blank. I did not know that. I will try that now.

Comment: @OP the second query should work, MySQL should be importing these empty columns as `''` unless you are specifying \N for the rows which should be null.

Answer (score 2):

```
delete from your_table
where certain_column is null
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE from `<tablename>`
WHERE `<columnname>` is null
```

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from table_name where column=''
```

Answer (score 0):

delete from table_name where column_name is null; 
this query will definitely work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about count of data. Mysql can handle it. Just write:

```
 DELETE FROM `Businesses` WHERE `WEBADDRESS` = '';
```